# How do i force GridLayout to always have 7 columns

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

(This is on Java Swing)

I created a `gridLayout(6,7)`, however it looks like it prefers to comply the Vertical requirement with higher priority than the horizontal.
I mean, it will always have `6` rows, disregarding the `7` columns i want it to have. I want it so it always has `7` columns, i dont really care about the rows. (Its a calendar)

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: `however it looks like it prefers to comply the Vertical requirement with higher priority than the horizontal` - did you read the API description for the class? The API is the first place to look, not a forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the number of rows to `0` for the layout manager

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 7));
```